# How to do this as a single line "for" in Python

Tags: python

I have the test input as plain text.
I want to split it by line break and then by digit so it is stored in a list and each individual digit can be accessed via hmap[x][y] ([x] for the row and [y] for the column)

Below is how I have managed to do it buy I would like to know how this could be done as a single line "for statement"

```
#initial input

test_input="""2199943210
3987894921
9856789892
8767896789
9899965678"""

#split by line break

xhmap=[i for i in test_input.split('\n')]

#split by digit

hmap=[]
for i in range (0, len(xhmap)):
  hmap+=[[]]
  for j in xhmap[i]:
    hmap[i]+=j
```

Comment: Your code gives an error.

Comment: We normally call those a "listcomp" or list comprehension (or dict-, etc).  Might help with Google in the future

Comment: @PCM Apologies, I had an extra int() in there. fixed

Comment: You already have the answer in your own code... All you need is `xhmap=[i for i in test_input.split('\n')]`. This is a list of strings which are themselves iterables and allow you to access with indexing. You could even simplify it to `test_input.splitlines()`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you want list-comprehension:

```
hmap = [[j for j in line] for line in test_input.split('\n')]
```

If you're reading a text (which presumably you are), then you don't even need the inner comprehension, just use `list` function:

```
hmap = [list(line) for line in test_input.split('\n')]
```

Answer (score 2):

Double list comprehension is the answer. You want your outer list to split the string into rows and then inner list to split each row into digits.

`hmap=[[int(digit) for digit in row] for row in test_input.split('\n')]`